# git .gitignore не игнорирует файл, который хранит пароли

Tags: git, gitignore, circleci

Всем привет, проблема вот в чем:

Деплою rails проект с помощью capistrano на продакш сервер, подключаю этот проект к тому же git репозиторию с которого его деплоил capistrano, добавляю файл с паролями config/secrets.yml в .gitignore, но когда пытаюсь сделать git pull origin master, получаю ошибку:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>           config/secrets.yml

команда `git rm --cached config/secrets.yml` выдает ошибку:

> fatal: pathspec 'config/secrets.yml' did not match any files

Возможно проблема возникает из-за того, что в гит репозитории находится этот файл.

Задача состоит в том, что бы настроить continuous Integration с помощью circleCi, если в репозитории произошли изменения - то задеплоить приложение на продакш сервер, как это сделать я разобрался, а вот как это сделать что бы задеплоить игнорируя файл secrets.yml нет. За ранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: если файл уже добавлен в репозиторий, то gitignore не работает.

Answer (score 4):

Переместите этот файл в другое место, обновитесь, чтобы получить версию файла с сервера. Замет выполните `git update-index --skip-worktree config/secrets.yml` - это заставить git не забирать изменения из вашей рабочей копии. Затем верните ранее сохраненный файл.